# Amplify Auth Plugin for Flutter Error "Plugin not added"

Tags: flutter, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify with Flutter to do the user authentication but I can't retrieve the user's session. The error I get:

```
> Launching lib/main.dart on 2109119DG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://xxxx
Syncing files to device 2109119DG...
I/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(27806): Added Auth plugin
E/flutter (27806): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: AmplifyException(message: Auth plugin has not been added to Amplify, recoverySuggestion: Add Auth plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling Auth related APIs, underlyingException: null)
E/flutter (27806): #0      AuthCategory.fetchAuthSession (package:amplify_core/src/category/amplify_auth_category.dart:189:11)
E/flutter (27806): #1      _MyAppState.isUserSignedIn (package:base_app/main.dart:37:39)
E/flutter (27806): #2      _MyAppState.build (package:base_app/main.dart:47:21)
E/flutter (27806): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
E/flutter (27806): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
E/flutter (27806): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter (27806): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (27806): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (27806): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
E/flutter (27806): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (27806): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (27806): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (27806): #12     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1195:16)
E/flutter (27806): #13     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1164:5)
E/flutter (27806): #14     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:18)
E/flutter (27806): #15     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2605:19)
E/flutter (27806): #16     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1110:13)
E/flutter (27806): #17     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:945:7)
E/flutter (27806): #18     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (27806): #19     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (27806): #20     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (27806): #21     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (27806): #22     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (27806): 
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): Using the SignInProviderConfig from `awsconfiguration.json`.
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): Inspecting user state details
I/flutter (27806): Successfully configured
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): Inspecting user state details
I/TetheringManager(27806): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.dontknow.base_app
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): hasFederatedToken: false provider: cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxx
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): hasFederatedToken: false provider: cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxx
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): hasFederatedToken: true provider: cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxx
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): waitForSignIn: userState:SIGNED_IN
D/AWSMobileClient(27806): getCredentials: Validated user is signed-in
```

I strictly folloed the [AWS tutorials](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#check-the-current-auth-session) and added the plugin before calling "configure" in the code. What is also odd, is that in the line before the error occurs the plugin is actually loaded.

Here is my main.dart:

```
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito());
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      print('Successfully configured');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Error configuring Amplify: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isUserSignedIn() async {
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession();
    return result.isSignedIn;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Authenticator(
      child: MaterialApp(
        builder: Authenticator.builder(),
        home: FutureBuilder(
            future: isUserSignedIn(),
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return Text("logged in");
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a suitable fix fitting my skilllevel here [github-repo](https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/30DaysOfFlutter/blob/main/day23_user_authentication/lib/main.dart)

I added a state variable `_isAmplifyConfigured` which is set true when `_configureAmplify()` finishes. In the builder I then check wheter amplify is configured or not with a simple if-else. Here the full code:

```
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_authenticator/amplify_authenticator.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'amplifyconfiguration.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isAmplifyConfigured = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito());
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      setState(() => _isAmplifyConfigured = true);
      print('Successfully configured');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Error configuring Amplify: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isUserSignedIn() async {
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession();
    return result.isSignedIn;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Authenticator(
      child: MaterialApp(
        builder: Authenticator.builder(),
        home: _isAmplifyConfigured? FutureBuilder(
            future: isUserSignedIn(),
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return Text("logged in");
              }
            }): Text("not logged in")
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do asynchronous work in `initState()`, but this is not guaranteed to complete before `build()` is called. Therefore, when you call `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()` in your `build()` function, the initialisation and configuration is not complete.

You should try calling `_configureAmplify()` before `runApp()`.

To make this work, you also need to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before `_configureAmplify()`.

As a general advise, this kind of work does not belong into UI code (pages or widgets). Rather is should be done in the app's state management.

Comment: Makes total sense. Since I just copied this from the AWS tutorial I am wondering why they do it this way if it is not working properly.

Comment: @Muleque It is very well possible it worked for them, since this kind of race condition yields totally unpredictable results. Can be really hard to find if everything has been working until you add some trivial change to your widget tree.

Comment: unfortunately when putting the _configureAmplify() in the main, I get another error: `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized.` I am stuck here.

Comment: Yes. That's because the flutter bindings have not been initialized at the time. You also need to call `WidgetsBinding.ensureInitialized()` before configuring Amplify.